# Android Twitter Connect issues

Tags: android, twitter, networkonmainthread

I want to my app to connect with twitter on click of the button, but I'm getting this error:
"NetworkOnMainThreadException" error while I click on the connect button.
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = ""; // place your consumer key here
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = ""; // place your consumer secret here

    // Preference Constants
        static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
        static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "";
        static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "";
        static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

        static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "h";

        // Twitter oauth urls
        static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "";
        static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
        static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

        // Login button
        Button btnLoginTwitter;
        // Update status button
        Button btnUpdateStatus;
        // Logout button
        Button btnLogoutTwitter;
        // EditText for update
        EditText txtUpdate;
        // lbl update
        TextView lblUpdate;
        TextView lblUserName;

        // Progress dialog
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // Twitter
        private static Twitter twitter;
        private static RequestToken requestToken;

        // Shared Preferences
        private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

        // Internet Connection detector
        private ConnectionDetector cd;

        // Alert Dialog Manager
        AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
                if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                    // Internet Connection is not present
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                            "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
                    // stop executing code by return
                    return;
                }

                // Check if twitter keys are set
                if(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0 || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0){
                    // Internet Connection is not present
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens", "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
                    // stop executing code by return
                    return;
                }

                // All UI elements
                btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
                btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
                btnLogoutTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);
                txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
                lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
                lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);

                // Shared Preferences
                mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                        "MyPref", 0);

                /**
                 * Twitter login button click event will call loginToTwitter() function
                 * */
                btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // Call login twitter function
                        loginToTwitter();
                    }
                });

                /**
                 * Button click event to Update Status, will call updateTwitterStatus()
                 * function
                 * */
                btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Call update status function
                        // Get the status from EditText
                        String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();

                        // Check for blank text
                        if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                            // update status
                            new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
                        } else {
                            // EditText is empty
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please enter status message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                /**
                 * Button click event for logout from twitter
                 * */
                btnLogoutTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // Call logout twitter function
                        logoutFromTwitter();
                    }
                });

                /** This if conditions is tested once is
                 * redirected from twitter page. Parse the uri to get oAuth
                 * Verifier
                 * */
                if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
                    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                        // oAuth verifier
                        String verifier = uri
                                .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                        try {
                            // Get the access token
                            AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                                    requestToken, verifier);

                            // Shared Preferences
                            Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                            // After getting access token, access token secret
                            // store them in application preferences
                            e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                            e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                                    accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                            // Store login status - true
                            e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                            e.commit(); // save changes

                            Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                            // Hide login button
                            btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            // Show Update Twitter
                            lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // Getting user details from twitter
                            // For now i am getting his name only
                            long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                            User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                            String username = user.getName();

                            // Displaying in xml ui
                            lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username + "</b>"));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // Check log for login errors
                            Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            /**
             * Function to login twitter
             * */
            private void loginToTwitter() {
                // Check if already logged in
                if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                    Configuration configuration = builder.build();

                    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
                    twitter = factory.getInstance();

                    try {
                        requestToken = twitter
                                .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                        this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
                    } catch (TwitterException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    // user already logged into twitter
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            /**
             * Function to update status
             * */
            class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                /**
                 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                 * */
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pDialog.show();
                }

                /**
                 * getting Places JSON
                 * */
                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                    Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
                    String status = args[0];
                    try {
                        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

                        // Access Token 
                        String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                        // Access Token Secret
                        String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
                        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

                        // Update status
                        twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

                        Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
                    } catch (TwitterException e) {
                        // Error in updating status
                        Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                /**
                 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
                 * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
                 * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
                 * **/
                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    // updating UI from Background Thread
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            // Clearing EditText field
                            txtUpdate.setText("");
                        }
                    });
                }

            }

            /**
             * Function to logout from twitter
             * It will just clear the application shared preferences
             * */
            private void logoutFromTwitter() {
                // Clear the shared preferences
                Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
                e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
                e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
                e.commit();

                // After this take the appropriate action
                // I am showing the hiding/showing buttons again
                // You might not needed this code
                btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lblUserName.setText("");
                lblUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            /**
             * Check user already logged in your application using twitter Login flag is
             * fetched from Shared Preferences
             * */
            private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
                // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
                return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
            }

            protected void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Where is it going wrong?

Comment: can you put log here?

Comment: 11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669): Process: com.example.tatatwitterconnect, PID: 2669
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1166)

Comment: 11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)

Comment: 11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:390)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:343)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)

Comment: 11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:158)

Comment: 11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:102)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:121)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:104)

Comment: 11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:276)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.example.tatatwitterconnect.MainActivity.loginToTwitter(MainActivity.java:232)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.example.tatatwitterconnect.MainActivity.access$1(MainActivity.java:219)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.example.tatatwitterconnect.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:119)

Comment: 11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4658)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19461)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)

Comment: 11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
11-26 16:30:28.481: E/AndroidRuntime(2669):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score -2):

Write below code into your MainActivity file after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

And below import statement into your java file.

```
import android.os.StrictMode;
```

good luck

Comment: 11-26 16:41:56.531: W/System.err(4946): 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
11-26 16:41:56.531: W/System.err(4946): SSL is required

Comment: this is the error it is giving now.the application is hanging for a while and then there is nothing but just the home page.